# How do I say to express giving a definite value/choice to a variable/possibilities in math or physics?

Tags: phrase-request, mathematics

In math or physics, there are some variables or possibiliies to be specified. I wonder how to express giving a definite value/choice for a variable/ possibilities. In the following I just give a few examples to clarify what I intend to ask.

The simplest example is a function, say, `y=f(x)=x+3`, which is a variable `(y)` varying with another variable `(x)`. When I want to say *"I give `x` a certain value to get a value for `y`",* how can I say in a concise way? Can I say, for instance, *"I fix/take/set `x` to be 2 to get 5 for `y`."?*

Another example is the gauge condition, which is a condition which can be adjusted without affecting physics. Can I say *"I fix/take/set the gauge condition to be the Lorentz gauge (a gauge choice in electromagnetics)."?*

Still another example is coordinate systems, which are the reference frames one takes to describe what (s)he observes. Can I say *"I fix/take/set the coordinate system to be the Lorentz frame (a reference frame in relativity)."?*

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but see: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81833/counterpart-to-given-in-a-mathematical-problem-statement

Comment: I'd personally use *choose* (e.g., *We choose a certain value of x to satisfy a certain condition*; *We choose x to be 2 so/such that y = 5 (because y = x+3)*. I refrain from posting an answer because I'm not sure about your *Lorentz frame* example.

Comment: I originally wanted to and have used "choose" in this kind of contexts naturally for long without doubt. But yesterday I posted a question in StackExchange to ask the usage of "choose", then someone replied me using "choose" in that way is incorrect. The correct way according to her response should be "choose 2 to be x". But I prefer to find a verb which can let the variable/possibilities prior to the value/choice.

Comment: "Choose x to be 2" is better than "choose 2 to be x." I've edited below and posted an answer [there](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/85085/20777).

Answer (score 3):

The shortest answer is **let** as in:
***Let*** x=2.
Because y=x+3,
y=5.

This is also called variable **assignment** and you can talk about **assigning** a value to a variable, especially in the context of implementing your math/physics with some computer programming.  This particular verb doesn't work as well for your nonvariable examples like gauge condition, unless you're discussing storage of that value in a variable in computer code.

The terms you ask about, **fix** and **set**, could also be used, and imply that you can control the value you are putting in.  For example, *if we **fix/set** the weight of this container to 10 kg, it will take 30 N of force to move it across this surface.*  The two terms are basically interchangeable in this context, but **fix** has a **slightly** greater implication that you're putting in some value that's somehow better than some existing value.

**Choose** is OK too, and per comments (as well as [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/85085/20777)) it's apparently what you prefer.  When you use "choose" (in whatever conjugated form is appropriate) you should specify who is doing the choosing.

Compared to **fix**, **set**, or **choose**, **take** (the companion verb of also-acceptable-but-more-passive **[given](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81833/counterpart-to-given-in-a-mathematical-problem-statement)**) has more of a connotation that you are reading some value, e.g. from a real-world measurement or other exogenous source.  For an example, if you're explaining the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) you can say "*if we **take** the temperature to be 25 degrees Celsius, we can see from this equation that...*"

Comment: What do you mean by "in whatever conjugated form is appropriate"? Do you mean both "choose x to be 2" and "choose 2 to be x." are appropriate?

Comment: No, I mean "we choose x to be 2" (present tense) is appropriate if you're doing a live demonstration at the board, "we chose x to be 2" (past tense) is appropriate if you're writing in a paper about how you set up the first parts of an experiment, "you will choose the Ace of Spades" if you're a future-predicting magician, "he would have chosen the passcode to be 1234" if you're considering possibilities from the past, etc.  Reversing the order of x and 2 is not related to conjugating the verb "choose."

Comment: Thank you. It turns out "conjugate" in Grammar refers to the tenses of a verb.

Comment: So is "choose" also the best word choice for my latter two examples? That is to say, saying "I choose the gauge condition to be the Lorentz gauge." is better than "I fix/take/set the gauge condition to be the Lorentz gauge." and saying "I choose the coordinate system to be the Lorentz frame." is better than "I fix/take/set the coordinate system to be the Lorentz frame."?